# Orthogonal complement of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ spanned by $(1,2)$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Have a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $W$ is spanned by
>   $\{(1,2)\}$. Determine $W^\perp$.

Well then, clearly $W$ is a line in a 2D space. So I guess $W^\perp$ is a line, too.

$W^\perp$ are all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are orthogonal to any vector of $W$.

Since $W$ is a line, any vector in $W$ is a scalar product of $(1,2)$. So, $W^\perp$ is composed by vectors that are orthogonal to $(1,2)$:

$$W^\perp = \{(a,b) \ \ : \ \ (a,b)\cdot (1,2) = 0\}$$

So we have a system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} a \cdot 1 = 0\\ b \cdot 2 = 0 \end{cases}$$

Therefore

$$(a,b) = (0,0)$$

So

$$W^\perp=span\{(0,0)\}$$

... This isn't right... Shouldn't it be $(-2,1)$ or $(2,-1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{cases} a \cdot 1 = 0\\ b \cdot 2 = 0 \end{cases} should be $$a\times 1+b\times 2 =0$$
Therefore, you've got $(-2\alpha ,\alpha)$ where $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$